# Update and modify data in MySQL with adding new items and removing items, which are not in an update patch

Tags: mysql, merge, updates, insert-update

From time-to-time, my system generates JSONs with the current state of the data to be stored in MySQL DB. As long as these JSONs are small, there is no issue to apply updates by `DELETE` the entire current data from the table and `INSERT` data from JSON.

However, this approach is not suitable if the size of JSONs becomes significant.

Obviously, for «data to be added» case I can use `INSERT`, the problems begin when I have to identify removed data. The key idea: if the items are in JSON, then *insert* them, but if the existing in the DB items are not in the JSON anymore, thus, it should be *removed*.

Can the `DELETE`/`INSERT` approach be replaced with MySQL *built-in* merge-like functionality to apply the data update on DB? Or the only way is to implement the merge logic manually?